# Create a function to perform a T-Test in python

Tags: python

I'm using the following code to compute t-test in python

```
import researchpy as rp
import scipy.stats as stats

summary, results = rp.ttest(group1= dfEnt['HA'][df['Q8_5'] == 0], group1_name= "Nascent",
         group2= dfEnt['HA'][df['Q8_5'] == 2], group2_name= "Established")
```

How could I create a function that will provide as argument the name of the dataframe with the column on which I want to compute the t-test. I would like for example to rune t-test with dfEnt['IA] or dfSel['IA],...
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

What version of researchpy are you using? In the newest version that can be completed using -difference_test()-. The code below will conduct a ttest on the column -Exercise- which contains the group categories using the values from -StessReactivity-.

```
import pandas as pd
import researchpy as rp
import numpy as np


np.random.seed(12345678)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size= (100, 2)),
                  columns= ['No', 'Yes'])

df["id"] = range(1, df.shape[0] + 1)

df2 = pandas.melt(df, id_vars = "id", value_vars = ["No", "Yes"],
                  var_name = "Exercise", value_name = "StressReactivity")

rp.difference_test("StressReactivity ~ C(Exercise)",
                   data = df2,
                   equal_variances = True,
                   independent_samples = True)
```